# I am having issues with resetting a single instance of a jquery countdown from an instance of a button of class reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/
in a bidding system project.
i am working with django for backend.
i have many countdown instances 
i have successfully gotten the countdown to work with some basic javascript countdown. but the problem i have is resetting each countdown to 15 seconds uniquely based on the bid button under it.

```
<div class="time-counter">
  <div data-countdown="2018/08/18 12:34:56"></div>
</div>
<div class="cart-btn">
  <a class="reset">Bid Now</a>
</div>

my js code below
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
    var finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
    finalDate = new Date(finalDate).getTime();
    console.log(finalDate);
    var $this = $(this);
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = finalDate - now;
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / 
        (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 
* 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        $this.html(`<span class="cdown hour">${hours}</span></span>
<span class="cdown minutes"><span class="time-count">${minutes}</span>
</span> <span class="cdown second"><span class="time-count">${seconds}
</span></span>`);
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Sold";
        }
    }, 1000);

    $('.reset').each(function () {
        $(this).click( function() {
            finalDate = finalDate + 15000;
            console.log(finalDate)
        })
    })

I appreciate any help i can get.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the issue is linking each button with its counter, right? If so you can use IDs or data-* attributes to uniquely identify each button / counter and pair them.

HTML:

```
<div data-counter="ctr-a" data-countdown="2018/08/18 12:34:56"></div>
<div data-counter="ctr-b" data-countdown="2018/08/18 12:34:56"></div>
<div data-counter="ctr-c" data-countdown="2018/08/18 12:34:56"></div>
<div data-counter="ctr-d" data-countdown="2018/08/18 12:34:56"></div>

<a data-counter="ctr-a" class="reset">Reset A</a>
<a data-counter="ctr-b" class="reset">Reset B</a>
<a data-counter="ctr-c" class="reset">Reset C</a>
<a data-counter="ctr-d" class="reset">Reset D</a>
```

JS (jQuery, which you seem to be using):

```
var finalDates = { // final date for each counter
    "ctr-a": new Date(...),
    "ctr-b": new Date(...),
    "ctr-c": new Date(...),
    "ctr-d": new Date(...)
};

$(".reset").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).data("counter"); // retrieves the data-counter attr
    var counter = $("[data-countdown][data-counter="+name+"]"); // retrieves all the HTML tags
    // with a data-countdown attr and with a data-counter attr matching the clicked button

    finalDates[name] += 15000; // delay the counter for this

    // and now your code ... this does not count down time, it just redraws the affected timers.
    // you still need to set up the timers to make it count down...
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = finalDates[name] - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // If you have multiple counters with the same name this will still redraw them all
    counter.html(
        `<span class="cdown hour">${hours}</span></span>
        <span class="cdown minutes"><span class="time-count">${minutes}</span>
        </span> <span class="cdown second"><span class="time-count">${seconds}
        </span></span>`
    );
});
```

Anything I might have missed, let me know :)

Comment: i am sorry if i've mislead you in anyway, my mission was to achieve a countdown for a bidding system that works like https://www.quibids.com 
so far the countdown is not in your solution, my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/realafe/04f2fd8k/

Comment: You already have the countdown in your code, I didn't provide the entire code, only the code you need to have multiple independent countdowns. If you read the code comments it states right there you still need to set up the timers to make it count down.